# How can I check if product is Grouped?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, php-5.4

How can I check if product is a Grouped Product?

I tried:

```
<?php if( $_products->isGrouped() ) ?>
```

but doesn't  work.

Comment: Is that a typo, or did you really use $_products (ending with s). By convention that is the collection, not the product model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way to check the product is grouped or not.

```
<?php if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'simple' ): ?>
//your code for simple products only
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped' ): ?>
//your code for grouped products only
<?php endif; ?>
```

So on.
Place this code in the `catalog/product/view.phtml`